# Apex classic report row colour change

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I am dont really know much about java so i am struggling. have a classic report in oracle apex express

I have a table that contains a list of areas and this has some percentages in.

I wanted to colour the rows depending on the percentage.

I followed a tutorial and with it i am able to colour lines in my table.
[Tutorial](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3739809/change-row-color-based-on-column-value-apex-5-in-classic-report)
all good. but i actually wanted to show a different colour on the percentage
so i changed the header are to percentage and then put in a number and it wont change the colour.
I am not sure if it is because this is a calulated column and so isnt in the table? or mor e than likey my java isnt looking for a number. I did try changing it but i got into a real muddle.

any java gurus able to tell me??

```js
$('td[headers="AREA"]').each(function() {
  if ( $(this).text() === 'London' ) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({"color":"red"});
  }
  if ( $(this).text() === 'Wales' ) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({"color":"green"});
  }
  if ( $(this).text() === 'Scotland' ) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({"color":"blue"});
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not Java related question, move it to JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with java. Google "javascipt vs java" to see why.

Here is a step by step explanation of that example shown in the post. I'm using a query on the sample emp table with an additional column to calculate each employees salary as a percentage of the highest salary.

##### report

This is the select statement for the classic report:

```
select e.empno,
       e.ename,
       e.job,
       e.mgr,
       e.hiredate,
       e.sal,
       e.comm,
       e.deptno,
       ROUND(e.sal/em.sal * 100) as pct
  from emp e
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(sal) as sal FROM EMP) em
```

Note that I aliased the percentage column as "pct". That is of importance later.

Now run the report and use the chrome (I use chrome) dev tools to inspect the column header. Left click the column header and click "inspect". Note the id of the column is "PCT".

[image]

##### javascript

Now test the javascript. The column header id is "PCT", so that value is needed to determine the column that is referenced. I modified the javascript a bit and came up with the code below.

Note the `headers="PCT"`.

Note `{"color":"somevalue"}` will change font color only. Change that to `{"background-color":"somevalue"}` if you want the have a row background or combine both to play with background and font color. (example `{"background-color":"pink","color":"blue"}`)

```
$('td[headers="PCT"]').each(function() {
  let val = parseInt($(this).text());
  if ( val === 100 ) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({"color":"red"});
  }
  if ( val > 50 && val < 100 ) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({"color":"green"});
  }
  if ( val < 50 ) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({"color":"blue"});
  }
});
```

Test this. That's very simple. Open the console window in the chrome dev tools and paste the javascript. Press enter. The javascript will execute on the page and apply the css. You can use this technique to tweak your javascript. Once you have it working as expected, add the code to a dynamic action.

[image]

##### dynamic action

Create a dynamic action with following specifications (this is take from the post you referred to):

- Name : give appropriate name
- Event : After Refresh
- Selection Type : Region
- Region : select your classic report region
- Condition : No condition
- Action : Execute JavaScript Code
- Fire on Initialization : Yes
- Code: (use code above)

That's it. Test this. Play with it. Learn how to do this yourself - the above should be a good start.